# Racoon IPsec-SA expired: ESP/Tunnel

Tags: linux, vpn, ipsec

Hello my vpn link vpn does not connect anymore and gives me the following logs thank you to help me please:

```
Jun 19 08:06:25 FwME racoon: INFO: IPsec-SA established: ESP/Tunnel 89.30.97.2[500]->57.66.111.252[500] spi=33810496(0x203e840)
Jun 19 08:06:25 FwME racoon: DEBUG: ===
Jun 19 08:06:43 FwME racoon: DEBUG: pk_recv: retry[0] recv()
Jun 19 08:06:43 FwME racoon: DEBUG: get pfkey EXPIRE message
Jun 19 08:06:43 FwME racoon: DEBUG2:  02080003 14000000 00000000 00000000 02000100 08afd47a 00030000 00000000 04000300 00000000 00000000 00000000 1e000000 00000000 00000000 00000000 04000200 00000000 00000000 00000000 f5854759 00000000 00000000 00000000 03000500 00200000 02000000 39426ffc 00000000 00000000 03000600 00200000 02000000 591e6102 00000000 00000000 02001300 02000000 00000000 00000000
Jun 19 08:06:43 FwME racoon: INFO: IPsec-SA expired: ESP/Tunnel 57.66.111.252[0]->89.30.97.2[0] spi=145740922(0x8afd47a)
Jun 19 08:06:43 FwME racoon: DEBUG: no such a SA found: ESP/Tunnel 57.66.111.252[0]->89.30.97.2[0] spi=145740922(0x8afd47a)
```